# How to create unallocated space in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gparted

I've already installed ubuntu 16.04 and I want to manage my partitions.
I opened **GParted** and I wanted to have "unallocated space" to install another OS on it.
I selected one partition and chose **Resize/Move** option. But I can't do the resize because Minimum size and Maximum are the same!

[image]

Comment: I can not move the righthand slider, even when I type a number, it remove to the original number  "0" when I leave the "Free space following" box :(

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for your link. I think that the second answer is useful but I didn't understand this comment ** You can't do it from your installed system since the partition will be in use. **

Comment: You need to boot from LiveUSB to do it.

Comment: Really I'm new on Ubuntu. Can you tell me what do you mean with LiveUSB ;)

Comment: I mean a USB stick with Ubuntu installer on it. Are you sure you can install another OS with this kind of skills?